# Construct a deterministic finite machine for the language $(01)^*$

Tags: solution-verification, formal-languages, finite-state-machine

I need to construct a deterministic finite machine that recognizes the language $(01)^*$. This is the machine I have constructed, is it valid?

Let $M=(Q,\Sigma,\delta,q_0,F)$ where $Q = \{q_0,q_1\}$ is the set of states, $\Sigma=\{0,1\}$ is the alphabet, $\delta:Q\times\Sigma\to Q$ is the transition function given by

[image: finite machine]

$q_0$ is the start state, and $F=\{q_0\}$ is the set of accept states.

Comment: No. It won't accept $00$. What is the alphabet?

Comment: You just need a single accepting state and two arrows that loop around back onto the same state accepting $0$ and $1$ as inputs respectively.

Comment: @copper.hat $\sum = \{ 0,1\} $

Comment: What is the transition from state $q_0$ when the next input character is "1"? ... from state $q_1$ when the next ... is "0"?  Could this machine accept "0", "010", "01010", ...?

Comment: @copper.hat why should it accept $00$? Is $(01)^*$ not $\{ 01, 0101, 010101, \dots \} $ ?

Comment: @EricTowers see my comment above please.

Comment: @NimaKimi: That is usually written $(01)^*$. Partly that is why I was asking about the alphabet.

Comment: @copper.hat Indeed, I have edited my question.

Comment: @copper.hat So my finite machine is correct with change I made on my question?

Comment: That only resolves the third of my three questions.  Is your convention for unspecified transitions that they are automatically non-accepting or that they do not result in a change of state?

Comment: What happens if the input is $11$? Or even just $1$?

Comment: To put Eric Towers’ question differently, is this “finite machine” that you’re supposed to construct deterministic or non deterministic?

Comment: @amd thanks for clarifying it.

Comment: @EricTowers the finite machine is deterministic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your example won't work because the DFA must have at least three states. Let $M=(Q,\Sigma,\delta,q_0,F)$ where $Q = \{q^0,q^1,q^\Delta\}$ is the set of states, $\Sigma=\{0,1\}$ is the alphabet, $\delta:Q\times\Sigma\to Q$ is the transition function given by
$$
\begin{array}{c|cc}
q\overset{\LARGE\setminus}{\phantom{.}}\overset{\Large i}{\phantom{l}}&0&1\\\hline
q^0&q^1&q^\Delta\\
q^1&q^\Delta&q^0\\
q^\Delta&q^\Delta&q^\Delta
\end{array},
$$
$q_0=q^0$ is the start state, and $F=\{q_0\}$ is the set of accept states. Then $M$ recognizes the language described by the regular expression $(01)^*$.

Comment: Thank you. Is the visualization of this transition function I made correct? https://imgur.com/61r0cDa

Comment: where $q_3 = q_\Delta$